# Most efficient way to read the number of XML nodes directly under the root element

Tags: c#, xml, performance, stream

I need to count the number of nodes that are places directly under the root element in an XML stream. I don't care about any of the subnodes.

For example, for the following XML it should return 4:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<root>
  <node1>
    <subnode1_1>
      <subnode_1_1_1>
        <subnode_1_1_1_1>…</subnode_1_1_1_1>
      </subnode_1_1_1>
      <subnode_1_1_2>…</subnode_1_1_2>
    </subnode1_1>
  </node1>
  <node2 />
  <node3>
    <subnode3_1>…</subnode3_1>
    <subnode3_2>…</subnode3_2>
    <subnode3_3>…</subnode3_3>
  </node3>
  <node4>…</node4>
</root>
```

What is a most efficient (I care about execution time) way to do this in C#? Assume that I have and XML body as `Stream`.

Comment: It seems you only want to count element nodes. Is that right?

Comment: Yes, but only the ones that are directly under the root node.

Comment: For clarity, you should say "element" when you mean element. "Root node" would be the document as a whole. An XML 1.1 document has at least: the xml declaration node and the root element node.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're unlikely to get more efficient than:

```
public static int GetImmediateChildrenCount(Stream stm)
{
  using(stm)
  {
    XmlReaderSettings settings = new XmlReaderSettings();
    settings.CheckCharacters = false; //optomisation - best avoided.
    settings.DtdProcessing = DtdProcessing.Ignore;
    int count = 0;
    using(XmlReader rdr = XmlReader.Create(stm, settings))
      while(rdr.Read())
        if(rdr.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element && rdr.Depth == 1)
          ++count;
    return count;
  }
}
```

Without actually writing a specialised parser to do just that.

The above scans through the an `XmlReader` ignoring everything except what the depth of starting, ending and empty element tags are, and incrementing its tally if the depth is `1`; that is, directly below the root node.

It's certainly going to be faster than anything that constructs an `XDocument` or `XmlDocument` because it doesn't spend time and memory doing so, though if you were going to use the `XDocument` or `XmlDocument` for something else, then those approaches would be faster (the counting bit is fast for them, and the time spent constructing the object is already spent).

If you were going to read several such documents and they had a lot of xml names (element and attribute names, namespace names and namespace prefixes) in common, then you would do well to keep a cache of `NameTable` objects that you passed into the `settings.NameTable` property. NameTables aren't thread-safe, so you can't just use the same one, but they are most expensive when "learning" new names, and reusing them gives a subsequent performance boost. But this is true **only** if there are a lot of names the same in each document; if the documents are very different, they don't benefit from the "prior knowledge" and you're just wasting cycles moving them around instead of garbage collecting the default one you are given with each new `XmlReader`. (In fact you're making their lookups very slightly slower).

If you **really** want the absolutely most efficient possible, then you can beat the above by reading through the stream and keeping track of `<...>`, `</...>` and `<.../>`, but you also have to handle a bunch of special cases, so your gain over the above is unlikely to be enough to make the effort worth it.

Rough figures for 10000 iterations with your example:

```
XmlDocument:                     2387373
XDocument:                       1942206
XmlReader:                       1872387
XmlReader with reused NameTable: 1864708
```

Rough figures for 100 iterations with a 136KiB file based on your example:

```
XmlDocument:                     1887930
XDocument:                       1297059
XmlReader:                       996636
XmlReader with reused NameTable: 961763
```

Comment: There is a `Depth` property https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlreader.depth%28v=vs.110%29.aspx you could use instead of implementing it with your code.

Comment: @MartinHonnen thanks, I'd forgotten that, and the performance difference when it's not doing anything else with those elements is not to be sniffed at.

Comment: Thanks, your answer is pure genius! This is what I get from 100 iterations of reading 150 MB file ‒ your solution: 1131, XmlDocument: 5812, XDocument: 2898 (average times in ms).

Comment: I'm pretty impressed by `XDocument` here, given how convenient it is but certainly expected to beat it. Have you tried my approach both with and without reusing the `NameTable`? As I said, whether doing so helps or hinders depends on the data pushed through it, so it could be well to code with it in and then do test runs on real data both with and without to compare; it's a lot less work to stop holding onto the `NameTable` afterwards than to add that in.

Comment: Further micro-opt opportunities would be comparing `rdr.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element && rdr.Depth == 1`, `rdr.Depth == 1 && rdr.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element`, `rdr.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element & rdr.Depth == 1` and `rdr.Depth == 1 & rdr.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element`. All of those are logically equivalent, but with different likelihood of shortcutting for the first two, and of possibly avoiding branch mispredictions for the second two.

Answer (score 4):

You can knock it out in one line using Linq To XML:

```
var count = XDocument.Load(stream).Root.Elements.Count();
//count = 4
```

As far as efficiency, between the two answers given, my results are:

```
var sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();

XmlDocument xml = new XmlDocument();
xml.Load(stream);
int i = xml.LastChild.ChildNodes.Count; 

sw.Stop();
//971 ticks
```

and

```
var sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
var count = XDocument.Load(stream).Root.Elements().Count();
sw.Stop();
//860 ticks
```

A pretty negligible difference really, unless you're doing many many iterations

Comment: Why do you think it is the most efficient?

Comment: @bpiec I added some numbers

Comment: Running some loops on the sample from the question, I get yours doing better compared to `XmlDocument` than your numbers suggest; about 50% better, though still a bit slower than my approach.

Answer (score 2):

Easy as this:

```
XmlDocument xml = new XmlDocument();
xml.Load(/*path to your file*/);
int i = xml.LastChild.ChildNodes.Count; //as the xml header is first child
Console.WriteLine(i.ToString());
```

Or as @Jonesy says:

```
int i = XDocument.Load(/*your stream*/).Root.Elements.Count();
Console.WriteLine(i.ToString());
```

Both will ouput `4`.